# MSVC 2008 Express on command line

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, express

I want to compile a simple test.cpp file from command line of MS Visual C++  Express 2008

I can see the command and if I run

```
  cl test.cpp
```

I have the error: LNK1104 cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'.
I don't have any proble compiling files with the GUI.
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Solution at following link, seems to be the solution for your problem as well.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/Vsexpressvc/thread/426d85b4-db84-4c01-a9d4-d3fd025339c0

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, I know it works with the VS full version:

- open the Visual Studio Command Prompt
- type **devenv /porject myproject.vcproj /Rebuild /ProjectConfig Release**

I hope this works in the express edition. please comment if it is not working with you.

Comment: I really need to make cl work, because I have to compile PETSc

Comment: Collect all you source files into one vcproj then you can use devenv to build it. No need to use cl as you will be trying to do the makefile from scratch.